# ModelChoiceField in Django

Tags: django

i have used ModelChoiceField for one of filed in ModelForm:

```
class PackageModelForm(ModelForm):
    packageName = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Name", error_messages=     {'required': _(u'Please enter Package Name')})
    vehicleModelId = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Model",queryset=VehicleModels.objects.order_by('name').all())
    type_id =forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Package Type",queryset=Package_type.objects.order_by('name').all())       
    amount = forms.RegexField(regex="^([0-9]*)$",  label="Amount (in rupees)" , max_length=10, required=True, error_messages={'required': _(u'Enter Amount'), 'invalid': _(u'Enter a valid Amount.')})    



class Meta:
    model = Packages
    exclude = ('status','register', 'organizationId')
```

here type_id is foreign key to other model called 'Packages'

but here type_id filed is showing select options as 'package_type object ' in dropdown field instaed of 'airpot','railwaystation'

how to show object values as 'Airport,'Railwaystation'.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably forgot to set the unicode function:

```
class Packages(models.Model):
    # fields...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```